# View shows duplicate records when the article has multiple images

Tags: 7, views, media

In my article content type, I set the image filed as multiple images. However when I try to use the view to display the content. The article with one image will be displayed only one, but the article with multiple images will be displayed more than once.

For example, I have a article with 2 images, then in the view, this article will be load twice, these 2 article are the same except the image is different

it is a wired problem, in the view I even set the Distinct in the Query settings, but it doesn't work out

Comment: problem solved.

In the view -> content image setting -> SHOWMULTIPLE FIELD SETTINGS, I allow to display only one image

Comment: You might want to add this as your own answer to the question and mark it as an answer so this  won't show up as unsolved :) You can also group by content, this way you can still show multiple images.